# Is it possible to use locator() or identify() in an r-markdown file when the chunk output is inline instead of to the console?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a plot where I am trying to annotate specific points, and I want to use `locator()` for coordinates or `identify()` to label the points. However, if I use inline chunk output and run the chunk it doesn’t allow for me to click on the plot. When I divert the chunk output to console and the plot goes to the viewer in R studio I can then use said functions. Is it possible to get this to work with inline chunk output?

Comment: If you want something interactive, then the document must be *served* (and `reactive(..)`), not *rendered*.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.